# foreach item like button (access to variable through struct )(SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am developing MVVM app and I have two views and view model for one of them. One view for forEach cell, and another for forEach. So i want to implement like button in "cell" view, and i have no idea how to do it, because i cant edit data from cellView. Here is my code:

**TownsListView.swift**

```
struct TownsListView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = TownsViewModel()
     
     var body: some View {
         ScrollView() {
             ForEach(viewModel.towns) { town in
                TownView(name: town.name)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
             }
             
         }
         .onAppear {
           viewModel.getTowns()
         }
     }
 }
```

**TownView.swift**

```
struct TownView : View {
    
var name: String
  
  @StateObject var viewModel = TownViewModel()
  
  var body : some View {
    HStack {
    Text(self.name)
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {/* viewModel.setLike */}) {
            Image(systemName: "heart")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**TownsViewModel.swift**

```
class TownsViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var towns = [Town]()
    
    func getTowns() {
        
        for town in townsArray {
            towns.append(town)
        }
    }
}
```

**TownViewModel.swift**

```
class TownViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    func setLike() {
        //Here i want to implement like function
    }
}
```

**and Model.swift**

```
struct Town : Identifiable {
    
    var id : String = UUID().uuidString
    var name : String
    var liked : Bool
}

var paris = Town(name: "Paris", liked: false)
var london = Town(name: "London", liked: false)
var barcelona = Town(name: "Barcelona", liked: false)
var tokyo = Town(name: "Tokyo", liked: false)

let townsArray = [paris,london,barcelona,tokyo]
```

How to implement like function for toggle liked property of Town?

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? This doesn’t actually compile

Comment: You definitely need a minimal reproducible example, but I suspect you need a `binding`, 'EnvironmentObject' or 'ObservedObject' somewhere depending on what you are doing.

Comment: "i cant edit data from cellView" - yes. Instead, you have a closure in that cell view, like `let setLike: (Bool, ID) -> Void`. That closure will be set by the parent view, and eventually becomes `viewModel.setLike(state: Bool, for item: ItemID)`. You call it in your Button action. Then your view model modifies the model data, which in turn updates your view state, which in turn renders your view accordingly. The cell view has also a `let likeState: Bool` which gets set by the parent view.

Comment: @jnpdx - I've edited question, thx for reply

Comment: @Yrb - I've edited question, thx for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would handle this:

```
struct TownsListView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = TownsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView() {
            ForEach(viewModel.towns) { town in
                TownView(town: viewModel.bindingForTown(id: town.id))
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.getTowns()
        }
    }
}

struct TownView : View {
    
    @Binding var town: Town
    
    var body : some View {
        HStack {
            Text(town.name)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                town.liked.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "heart")
            }.foregroundColor(town.liked ? .red : .black)
        }
    }
}

class TownsViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var towns : [Town] = []
    
    func bindingForTown(id: String) -> Binding<Town> {
        .init {
            self.towns.first { $0.id == id }!
        } set: { newValue in
            self.towns = self.towns.map { $0.id == newValue.id ? newValue : $0 }
        }

    }
    
    func getTowns() {
        towns = townsArray
    }
}
```

This uses a custom binding to pass down to the `TownView`. If you can use Swift 5.5, this gets even easier and you can use `ForEach` with an automatic binding:

```
struct TownsListView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = TownsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView() {
            ForEach($viewModel.towns) { $town in
                TownView(town: $town)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.getTowns()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were overthinking this. Your model needs to provide the state of the app, not a function to change the state. Your views take that state and update them. I simply pulled your function stub out of `class TownViewModel` and added a bool `like`. In your view, all you need to do is have change the bool in the `TownView` button and you will change the state and have a record of it.
Model:

```
class TownViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var like: Bool = false
}
```

View:

```
struct TownView: View {
    var name: String
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = TownViewModel()
    
    var body : some View {
        HStack {
            Text(self.name)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.like.toggle() // Changes the "like" state
            }) {
                Image(systemName: (viewModel.like ? "heart.fill" : "heart")) // This is a simple
                // tertiary operator that takes the current value of the "like" and changes the heart to match.
            }
        }
    }
}
```